# Unable to target input fields by ClassName

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to target each input field by classname with my jquery/javascript code but it is not working. It can only work by targeting by ID. But I have many input fields with different ID's, so targeting each one by ID will get repetitive. How do I get my code to work so I'm able to target by classname? Here is my code, thank you:

```
<input type="text" class="inpfld">    

$(".inpfld").on('change keyup paste input',function(){
    var a=document.getElementsByClassName('inpfld').value;
    var b=a
    .replace(/hey/g,'hello')
    document.getElementsByClassName('inpfld').value=b;
});
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns "HTMLCollection" so you can't just call `.value` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**document.getElementsByClassName(class)** is supposed to return a HTML collection which is an array of all the elements within the site that use **class**.

You need to loop over this array using a for-loop to access all elements.

Also, if you want to get the **.value** property of the element that caused the change, keyup, paste and input events you need to add the special **e** parameter to the callback function and reference it as **e.target** inside.

```
$(".inpfld").on('change keyup paste input', function(e) {
  var a = e.target.value;
  var b = a.replace(/hey/g, 'hello')
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('inpfld');
  for (var a = 0; a < elements.length; a++) {
    elements[a].value = b;
  }
});
```

Comment: hm.. this seems like the right answer, but not sure why it's not working?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I missed another error in your code. I've edited my answer!

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean now. Thanks greatly for fixing my code and for the explanation!

Comment: No problem misner3456 - glad I could help!